# JSON ajax POST to Spring Portlet Controller @ResourceMapping conversion issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc

I'm trying to post JSON data to Spring Portlet Controller method. The Modelattribute object is nested. Here is the JSON:

```
$(document).on({    
  change: function() {
...
...
formData = {
            "name": "Demo",
            "id": 724,
            "periodId": 2015,
            "orgId": 4,
            "fieldGroupList": [{
                "name": "instructions",
                "label": "Instructions",
                "fieldList": [{
                    "name": "INSTRUCTION",
                    "instructionList": [{
                        "instructionText": "All enabled fields are required for completion of this screen."
                    }],
                    "type": "INSTRUCTION"
                }]
            }]
        };
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        async: "false",
        global: "false",
        url: validateURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json"        
    }).done(function(json){
        console.log(json);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("responseText: "+jqXHR.responseText);
    });
```

Controller:

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "validateURL")
    public void validate(@ModelAttribute(value = "formData") Measure measure,           
                        BindingResult bindingResult, ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("ab:::"+measure.getId());
}
```

Model:

```
public class Measure
{
    private String name;
    private List<MeasureFieldGroup> fieldGroupList = new ArrayList<MeasureFieldGroup>();
...
}
```

Also everything works fine if the JSON is changed to:

```
formData = {
                "name": "Demo",
                "id": 724,
                "periodId": 2015,
                "orgId": 4              
            };
```

Error in controller:

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'fieldGroupList[0][fieldList][0][instructionList][0][instructionText]' of bean class abc.measures.base.Measure]: Illegal attempt to get property 'fieldGroupList' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'fieldGroupList[0][fieldList][0][instructionList][0][instructionText]' of bean class [abc.measures.base.Measure]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'fieldGroupList[0][fieldList][0][instructionList][0][instructionText]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Set nor a Map; returned value was [abc.measures.base.MeasureFieldGroup@72fd67c]
```

My issue is very similar to 
[Post Nested Object to Spring MVC controller using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900840/post-nested-object-to-spring-mvc-controller-using-json) and
[Spring Portlet Jquery Ajax post to Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922248/spring-portlet-jquery-ajax-post-to-controller)

but can't use ResponseBody and RequestBody due to Spring Portlet. Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem when I try to bind JSON arrays to my model in Spring portlet MVC. I don't know whether the problem is spring or it is the way I build my JSON array.

The solution that I found was this:

Use JSON.stringify to turn an object (in this case an array) into a string with a JSON format. For example:

```
formData = {
        "name": "Demo",
        "id": 724,
        "periodId": 2015,
        "orgId": 4,
        "fieldGroupString": JSON.stringify(fieldGroupList)
    };
```

Where fieldGroupList is an array in javascript.

Then, you can use the ObjectMapper class of the jackson library to turn the JSON string into a list of objects in your model.

```
public void setFieldGroupString(String fieldGroupString) {
    if(fieldGroupString != null){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        fieldGroupList = new ArrayList<MeasureFieldGroup>();
        try {
            fieldGroupList = mapper.readValue(fieldGroupString,
                        new TypeReference<List<MeasureFieldGroup>>() {
                        });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Error in mapper");
        }
    }
}
```